# How to rotate a matrix in counterclockwise

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation

I use a 5*5 matrix as a moving Marine team.  Input an “L”, the matrix which has been rotated in counterclockwise way.  And input the second “L”, the matrix has been rotated again. Implement it with 2-dimension array.

Input: We will give you 5 rows of numbers, and for each row there will have 5 numbers. Input is between 1~9, reuse and separated by a space.

Output: Output the final matrix which has been rotated in counterclockwise, when you got the EOF (End of File). Each number has to be separated by a space.

For 3 rows as example

```
5 9 8    
7 2 1
4 3 6
```

change to :

```
8 1 6
9 2 3 
5 7 4
```

Comment: My answer is for rotating 5*5 matrix.

Comment: Let him do his own homework. Lets him learn to think and program.